# MongoDb - Does it help performance if all insertMany documents write to a single shard?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, sharding

I have a very large collection that is sharded on `hashed(user_id)`.

I have a script that pulls some file containing thousands of JSON lines, each one being an individual document, and writes them to the collection via `insertMany(ordered: false)`

I'm dealing with very large amounts of data and still running into CPU usage problems and slower than desired write speeds.

I know that Mongo suggests to [pre-split chunks, but only for an empty collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/), and of course ours will be populated after the initial load.

- Would it help boost performance if we pre-"bucketed" documents into a group keyed on `user_id`, and then executed an `insertMany` with all docs having the same `user_id`, since they would all go to the same shard, as opposed to mixed together? Or does Mongo still need to examine and "manually" balance each individual document in the `insertMany` even if they do all have the same `user_id`?

Comment: Wouldn't performance be better if the writes are distributed among all shards? Horizontal scaling and all that?

Comment: Well, we'd be sending lots of `insertMany` calls in a very short time span, e.g. writing 10k documents over a few minutes, but I'm trying to figure out if it's more efficient to pre-split those 10k documents into, say, 10 groups of 1k, where there are 10 different user_ids. All the writes in total are still going to be distributed among all shards either way

Comment: @ShaneOH what was your solution in the end? I'm also thinking about programming around an `InsertMany`, unfortunately.